# Anylogic, finding agents in a given radius

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have agents in a grid and for any arbitrary agent I want to somehow define a radius **r** and find all the other agents in that area given **r**. Is this possible, is there any implemented method for that in AnyLogic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'in a grid' you mean they are in continuous space but with integer (x,y) coordinates, you can use the standard function `agentsInRange` (which internally is using the standard function `distanceTo`).

If the agents are in an actual grid (i.e., a discrete space with (row, column) coordinates), you can't use the standard continuous/GIS space functions like `distanceTo` or `agentsInRange`. (You get runtime exceptions.)

In that case, you would have to write your own function to calculate distances (probably via Pythagoras' theorem given the row and column values) to each other agent, and return only those within the given threshold.

Below is such a sample function which assumes your agents are of type `Thing` and live in a population called `things` (and uses the straight-line distance in number-of-cells between agents as the 'distance between them'). You supply the function with the 'source' agent (that you want to get other agents in range of) and the desired range. (There are lots of slightly different ways of coding this depending on, for example, whether you want it to work for any population of any agent type.)

[image: sample range function]

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

There is. Check the `agentsInRange(double distance)` function, see help article [here](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FAgent.html&anchor=agentsInRange-java.lang.Iterable-double-).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This isn't correct if agents are in a grid (discrete space).

Comment: thanks @StuartRossiter, missed that in the original question :)